# jQuery upgrade breaks depending on how file is included

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSP page that includes v1.4.3 of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

I'd like to upgrade this, so I downloaded and copied the file `jquery-1.12.4.min.js` into the appropriate folder, then changed the `<script>` reference to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/jquery/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

The page breaks - many UI elements that depend on JavaScript fail to load properly.

However, if instead I use a web reference to include the new version of jQuery,

```
<script 
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

the page works as expected.  I've confirmed that the files at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js and at `../include/jquery/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js` have exactly the same contents, to the byte.

How is this possible?  Why does one method of inclusion break, but only for a certain version?

**Edit:** I think I'm closing in on it.  From viewing the page source, I notice that an included file is also including 1.4.3 locally.  My theory is that when I try to include jquery from a remote source, the server ignores it in favor of the local source.  Since that stays as 1.4.3 no matter what the remote source is, the page continues to work.  When I include 1.12.4 from a local source, however, the server gives it priority either because of its placement in the file or its greater version number -- or maybe there's just a conflict between the two local files.  In any event, the page breaks.

In other words, it's a combination of code that was deprecated between 1.4.3 and 1.12.4 and the server resolving conflicting sources differently depending on whether they're local or remote.  I'll test tomorrow and update.

Comment: how did you generate the local file? Maybe there's an encoding issue with copy/paste or something

Comment: Big jump from `1.4` to `1.12`. Check browser console for errors. Very likely there are methods used that have been deprecated like perhaps `live()`. `1.4` is about 10 years old

Comment: @KaiQing I downloaded the local file from https://code.jquery.com/, I don't remember if I copy & pasted it or found a direct download link.

Comment: @charlietfl Of course that was my first thought, but the page does work for `1.12` *if and only if* it's included as a weblink instead of as a local file.  It can't be deprecated code, or it would fail in both cases.

Comment: Are you sure the file loads? Check in network tab